# Why would `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` output nothing?

Tags: server, ip

I am trying to find out what is my public IP address and stumbled upon the above utility but it outputs nothing.

By the way, I am trying to ssh to my Ubuntu server outsite my private network but wonder if knowing my public ip can actually help me, in that I am unsure if I could just run `ssh @id@pub_ip` without further config, like I do over local net.

Comment: `curl icanhazip.com` works well. Yes, you will have to know your IP address (or a domain name assigned to that ip address) to access your computer from the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No response means that it didn't get an answer that was valid.  Remove the `+short` and look in the response header at the "status:" field.  SERVFAIL means the query failed, NXDOMAIN means no response, and any other error code that isn't NOERROR means something failed in the query.  The other possibility is you sent the DNS request but it's blocked on your network and timed out - `+short` hides all the useful error output.

I would suggest using `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` or `curl icanhasip.com` or similar services instead of relying on the DNS query to work.  It will get you your IP information as well and more reliably than DNS queries like the one you're trying will be.

Comment: Alright, but as I expected `ssh id@pub_ip` times out. Is there any further config I should do in addition to installing openssh?

Comment: @SamuelNihoul that's a much larger question that is outside the scope of what you're asking.  Timeouts indicate ports are not open or firewalls are at play.  If this is a VPS, there may be a firewall on the VPS admin side of things.  If this is your own home and your server is behind a router, then you need to port-forward on the router to make it forward the SSH traffic to your system.